# Renaming a JSON column for a UNION

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, union

*Remark: my example is overly simplified. In reality, I am dealing with a huge query. But to illustrate the issue/errors, let us resort to apples and oranges.*

My original query looked like this:

`SELECT 'FruitsCount' AS "Type", (SELECT count(id) as Counter, [Name] FROM Fruits group by name FOR JSON PATH) AS "Value"`

Which would result in something like. Let's refer to this as **Format A**

```
|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|        Type         |                                   Value                                      |
|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     FruitCount      |         [{"Counter":2, "Name":"Apple"},{"Counter":3, "Name":"Orange"}]       |
|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

However, now I want to create a union of Fruit and Vegetable counts. My query now looks like this

```
(SELECT count(id) as Counter, [Name] FROM Fruits group by name
UNION
SELECT count(id) as Counter, [Name] FROM Vegetables group by name)
FOR JSON PATH

|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                           JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B                                |
|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     [{"Counter":2, "Name":"Apple"},{"Counter":3, "Name":"Orange"},{"Counter":7, "Name":"Tomato"}]  |
|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

However, I want it in the format as before, where I have a Type and Value columns (Format A).

I tried doing the following:

```
SELECT 'FruitsCount' AS "Type", ((SELECT count(id) as Counter, [Name] FROM Fruits group by name
UNION
SELECT count(id) as Counter, [Name] FROM Vegetables group by name) FOR JSON PATH) as "Value"
```

However, I am presented with `Error 156: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.`

Then I tried the following:

```
SELECT 'FruitsAndVegCount' AS "Type", (SELECT count(id) as Counter, [Name] FROM Fruits group by name
UNION
SELECT count(id) as Counter, [Name] FROM Vegetables group by name FOR JSON PATH) as "Value"
```

However, I am presented with `Error 1086: The FOR XML and FOR JSON clauses are invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator.`

I'm stuck in trying to get my "union-ized" query to be in Format A.

**Update 1:** Here is the desired output

```
|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|        Type         |                                   Value                                                        |
|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  FruitAndVegCount   | [{"Counter":2, "Name":"Apple"},{"Counter":3, "Name":"Orange"},{"Counter":7, "Name":"Tomato"}]  |
|---------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The goal is to only have a single row, with 2 columns (Type, Value) where Type is whatever I specify (i.e. FruitAndVegCount) and Value is a JSON of the ResultSet that is created by the union query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the following statement is an option:

```
SELECT 
   [Type] = 'FruitAndVegCount',
   [Value] = (
      SELECT Counter, Name
      FROM (
         SELECT count(id) as Counter, [Name] FROM Fruits group by name
         UNION ALL
         SELECT count(id) as Counter, [Name] FROM Vegetables group by name
      ) t
      FOR JSON PATH
   )
```

Comment: I updated my original post with example output. Ultimately I need a single row with 2 columns.

Comment: Thank you! That works! Just so I understand the solution a bit more. Is `t` essentially an alias for a derived table? I assume that was the trick to getting the whole thing to work.

Comment: @MetalWing, yes, `t` is an alias.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with two columns, Type and Value, as follows.  Something like this

```
select 'FruitAndVegCount' as [Type],
        (select [Counter], [Name] 
         from (select count(id) as Counter, [Name] from #Fruits group by [name] 
               union all
               select count(id) as Counter, [Name] from #Vegetables group by [name]) u
          for json path) [Value];
```

Output

```
Type                Value
FruitAndVegCount    [{"Counter":2,"Name":"apple"},{"Counter":1,"Name":"pear"},{"Counter":2,"Name":"carrot"},{"Counter":1,"Name":"kale"},{"Counter":2,"Name":"lettuce"}]
```

Comment: I updated my original post with example output. Ultimately I need a single row with 2 columns (Type, Value)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, the goal is to have a single row! Type would be a custom column that I call "FruitAndVegCount", and the Value column is a JSON of the fruit and vegetable counts.

Comment: They're a little different in the way the 2nd column is named.  Cheers :)